# MC Dropout without weight decay -- how is the model precision calculated?

Tags: neural-networks, uncertainty, dropout

In the original [MC Dropout paper][1], the variance is calculated as the sum of two contributions, an sample variance (over the multiple forward passes), var$(y)$, plus a term quantifying the inverse model precision, $\mathbb{1}\tau^{-1}$, where $\tau=\frac{pl}{2N\lambda}$ with $p$ the probability to *not* drop out, $\lambda$ the L2 weight decay and $N$ the number of data points.

I'm looking at applying this in the case where no weight decay regularization is used. Trivially, one could conclude that for $\lambda=0$ there is no contribution of the inverse model precision term, but it seems strange that the dropout probability will then not be corrected for, when higher dropout probabilities lead to greater variance in the predictions.

[1]: Dropout as a Bayesian Approximation; Gal & Ghahramani; https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02157.pdf